# How to read a specific item of INI file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments

I want to read a specific item of my INI file, I have 5 Items in the section of my INI file, and I want to read 4 items, except items number 3.

I already tried to read all the items, but I can not find a way how to specify the item that I want to read and the format of the file that I read is like this:

```
Name Value
AA   12
BB   13
CC   14
DD   15
EE   16
```

I used this command to execute it.

```bsh
File1.ps1 Read-File -FilePath C:\Users\Data.ini -a_section Code -store C:\Users\
```

```bsh
function Read-File {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$a_section,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$store
    )

    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
            $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
            $ini_file[$section] = @{}
        } else {
            $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
            $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
        }
    }

     $Path_Store = $store
     $Get_Reg = $ini_file.($a_section)

     $Output = $Get_Reg | Out-File $Path_Store\Out_Test
}

$cmd, $params = $args
& $cmd @params
```

My expectation result, I have an output file like this

```
AA=12
BB=13
DD=15
EE=16
```

My INI File look like this:

```
[Name]
1=Joe
2=Grace

[Code]
AA=12
BB=13
CC=14
DD=15
EE=16
```

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a followup question: post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Get-IniSection {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$SectionName
    )

    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $Path | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
            $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
            $ini_file += @{ $section = @{} }
        } else {
            $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
            $ini_file[$section] += @{ $key = $value }
        }
    }

    return $ini_file[$SectionName]
}

$section = Get-IniSection -Path "C:\temp\test.ini" -SectionName "code"

$section.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "EE" }

$section.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" }

$section.GetEnumerator() | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in @("A1","AE","AP","AS","E1","E2","JP","M1","M2","N1","N2","P1","P2","P3","P4","PR","RU","S1","S2","W1","W2","W3","W4","ZH") } | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"

$section.GetEnumerator() | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in @("A1","AE","AP","AS","E1","E2","JP","M1","M2","N1","N2","P1","P2","P3","P4","PR","RU","S1","S2","W1","W2","W3","W4","ZH") } | 
    Foreach-Object { ($_.Value -split ",")[0] }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciated it. Sorry, I modify my question.

Comment: Added another use case for when you only required the first item in the value list

Comment: I modified this part `$Get_Reg = $ini_file.($SectionName)
     $Get_Reg = Get-IniSection $Path -SectionName $SectionName
     $Get_Reg.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "N3" }
     $Get_Reg.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" }
     $Get_Reg.GetEnumerator() | 
        Where-Object { $_.Name -in @("A1","AE","AP","AS","E1","E2","JP","M1","M2","N1","N2","P1","P2","P3","P4","PR","RU","S1","S2","W1","W2","W3","W4","ZH") } | 
        Foreach-Object { ($_.Value -split ",")[0] }
    $Get_Reg` but its not work

Comment: Did you remove the `return`? You should return the value from the function

Comment: No, I dont remove it `    return $ini_file[$SectionName]
}

$section = Get-IniSection -Path $Path -SectionName $Section_Name

$section.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "NE" }

$section.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" }

$section.GetEnumerator() | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in @("A1","AE","AP","AS","E1","E2","JP","M1","M2","N1","N2","P1","P2","P3","P4","PR","RU","S1","S2","W1","W2","W3","W4","ZH") } | 
    Foreach-Object { ($_.Value -split ",")[0] }`
I use this